# Is there any C++ function that allows me to convert a tiff format to a raw image?

Tags: c++

The raw image should be read the tiff tags number..
Thank you.

Comment: this is a pedantic point, but there is no function built into the C++ language that can do what you want. What you should ask is is there a C++ library that can convert a tiff to a raw image :P

Comment: oo..ok..actually,i not really understand about what i should do..my lecturer only said that we must extract just the data (from tiff tags number,eg:tagname=StripOffsets,NewSubFileType) and then, save it in .RAW form..we have to write our own program to incorporate the display module..i already search in internet,but i still cannot find the related one..i really don't know how to start the coding..already ask my friends,but they all also dont know how to do it..btw,thanks so much for all your kind of help here..:)

Answer (score 4):

Check out [LibTIFF](http://www.libtiff.org/) - from the manual:

> libtiff is a set of C functions (a
>   library) that support the manipulation
>   of TIFF image files. The library
>   requires an ANSI C compilation
>   environment for building and presumes
>   an ANSI C environment for use.
>
> libtiff provides interfaces to image
>   data at several layers of abstraction
>   (and cost). At the highest level image
>   data can be read into an 8-bit/sample,
>   ABGR pixel raster format without
>   regard for the underlying data
>   organization, colorspace, or
>   compression scheme. Below this
>   high-level interface the library
>   provides scanline-, strip-, and
>   tile-oriented interfaces that return
>   data decompressed but otherwise
>   untransformed. These interfaces
>   require that the application first
>   identify the organization of stored
>   data and select either a strip-based
>   or tile-based API for manipulating
>   data. At the lowest level the library
>   provides access to the raw
>   uncompressed strips or tiles,
>   returning the data exactly as it
>   appears in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

Comment: sory..may i ask again..actually,opencv is used for what purpose?i mean the function of opencv?is it the library or something else?i have checked it,but still not understand it,since i lack of knowledge in programming skill..i'm very sory for any incovenience..thanks..

Answer (score 0):

> [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) is the object-oriented C++ API to the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) image-processing library.